# Return union of entries from two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have two columns with entries as different numbers separated by comma and sorted (ascending). I need to get the union of those numbers in another column, that is without any repetition.

Example for a row:

```
column1- 10,12,14 | column2- 12,14,16 | result_column- 10,12,14,16
```

Concat won't work here. Is there any other way?

Comment: Never ever store data as comma separated items... It will only cause you lots of trouble! One value per row is the SQL way.

Comment: Working on the company's database. So, I will probably ask the guys maintaining data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Concat column values `select column1 + ',' + column2 from table`
2. Then [remove duplicate items from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882509/sql-server-2000-remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string) string.