# How to split a string that appears twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table temp with columnname `NAME` and data like this:

```
NAME
-------------
sumansuman
nehaneha
anjalianjali
```

I want to output like this:

```
NAME
-------------
suman 
neha
anjali
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882509/sql-server-2000-remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string

Answer (score 5):

If you are certain that each name is duplicated exactly then this should work

```
SELECT LEFT(name, LEN(name)/2) FROM temp
```

To catch rows where that is not the case:

```
SELECT name FROM temp
WHERE NOT name = LEFT(name, LEN(name)/2) + LEFT(name, LEN(name)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
     ('sumansuman')
    ,('nehaneha')
    ,('anjalianjali')
    ,('suman')
    ,('nehaanjali')

SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(NAME,1,len(NAME)/2) = SUBSTRING(NAME,(len(NAME)/2)+1,len(NAME)) 
                THEN SUBSTRING(NAME,1,len(NAME)/2) 
            ELSE NAME
        END
FROM @MyTable
```

the result is:

```
Output
------
suman
neha
anjali
suman
nehaanjali
```

Comment: @sumar, if you think this is the solution to you question, please mark it as answer so it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to make the query both more efficient (only perform LEFT and LEN once per row) and more readable:

```
with CTE as (
    select name, LEFT(name, LEN(name)/2) half from temp
)
select case name when half + half then half
  else name end as name
from CTE
```

If you want *only* the doubled names rectified:

```
with CTE as (
    select name, LEFT(name, LEN(name)/2) half from temp
)
select half as name
from CTE
where name + half + half
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Left** & **Right** function To make the logic readable:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
     ('sumansuman')
    ,('nehaneha')
    ,('anjalianjali')
    ,('suman')
    ,('nehaanjali')

SELECT  Case 
        when Left(NAME,len(NAME)/2) = Right(NAME,len(NAME)/2)
        then Left(NAME,len(NAME)/2) 
        else NAME 
        end
FROM @MyTable
```